# Lora E45-TTL-100 Basic Arduino setup

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, lora

I used this code to send data from the Arduino board to LoRa E45-TTL. The board seems to transmit data, but the receiving node doesn't seem to receive data. I am a real beginner to LoRa technology and any help is highly appreciated. The sending and receiving node codes I used are below:

Sender Node

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("000106,supun");
  delay(2000);
}
```

Receiver Node

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available()) {
    char x=Serial.read();
    Serial.println(x);
    delay(200);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://quadmeup.com/e45-ttl-100-not-transmitting-when-connected-to-arduino/) mentions a similar problem, with a hackish solution to close Serial and re-open it.

```
void loop() {
    Serial.print("Test");
    Serial.end();
    delay(30);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    delay(70); //The rest of requested delay. So 100 - 30 = 70
}
```